# Updating multiple rows dynamically according to a value in another table oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

table 1 :
employee id (ex.: 100000)  | status ((A)ctive/(I)nactive)

table 2 :
group (ex.:'ABC') | emplid (ex.: 100000) | has_documents((Y)es/(N)o)

I am trying to update a table in order to set every employees that is active to the state of has
_document = 'Y' and every employees thats inactive to has_documents = 'N'. An employee can be in multiple groups and has to be in a 'Y' state on every row containing its employee id if his state is active

This is a query I currently have:

```
UPDATE table2 t2 SET has_documents = 
(SELECT (CASE WHEN(
SELECT t1.HR_STATUS
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.EMPLID = t2.EMPLID ) = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) FROM DUAL);
```

And it returns the following error : **single-row subquery returns more than one row**

I have also tried this query which returned the same error :

```
UPDATE SYSADM.PS_RH_EE_LITIGATN P
  SET RH_RR_DOC = (SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT J.HR_STATUS FROM PS_JOB_CURR_VW J 
        JOIN SYSADM.PS_RH_EE_LITIGATN L 
        ON J.EMPLID = L.EMPLID WHERE J.EMPLID = P.EMPLID) 
    = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) FROM DUAL);
```

*example data :*

```
table 1:           table2:
empli_id | status  group | empli_id | has_docs
100000   | A       'ABC' | 100002   | null
100001   | I       'XYZ' | 100002   | null
100002   | A       'ABC' | 100001   | null
100003   | A       'ABC' | 100003   | null
100004   | I       'XYZ' | 100004   | null
```

*Desired Result :*

```
table 1:           table2:
empli_id |status   group | empli_id | has_docs
100000   | A       'ABC' | 100002   | Y
100001   | I       'XYZ' | 100002   | Y
100002   | A       'ABC' | 100001   | N
100003   | A       'ABC' | 100003   | Y
100004   | I       'XYZ' | 100004   | N
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Done I added an example :)

Comment: If you get single subquery returns more than one row it implies that the empid in table1 is not unique. Can you share the output of the query select count(*),empli_id from table1 group by empli_id order by 2 desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Employee may be in two groups, so use conditional aggregation and count inactive rows. Use such prepared data in `merge` statement and set `has_docs` to `Y` if cnt_inactive is 0, `N` otherwise.

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3be52a57faa9ef385ac7aad2b41a7c16)</sup>**

```
merge into table2 tgt
using (select empli_id, count(case status when 'I' then 1 end) cnt_inactive
         from table1 group by empli_id) src
on (tgt.empli_id = src.empli_id)
when matched then update set 
    has_docs = case cnt_inactive when 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge statement as following:

```
Merge into table2 t2
Using (select * from table1) t1
On (t1.empli_id = t2.empli_id)
When matched then 
Update set t2.has_document = decode(t1.status, 'A', 'Y', 'N')
```

Cheers!!